# Hadoop Total Order Partitioner

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, benchmarking, performance-testing

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

/**
 * Demonstrates how to use Total Order Partitioner on Word Count.
 */
public class TotalOrderPartitionerExample {
public static class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool {
private final static int REDUCE_TASKS = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new WordCount(), args);
      System.exit(exitCode);
    }

    @Override @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
      // Check arguments.
      if (args.length != 2) {
        String usage =
          "Usage: " +
          "hadoop jar TotalOrderPartitionerExample$WordCount " +
          "<input dir> <output dir>\n"
        System.out.printf(usage);
        System.exit(-1);
      }

      String jobName = "WordCount";
      String mapJobName = jobName + "-Map";
      String reduceJobName = jobName + "-Reduce";

      // Get user args.
      String inputDir = args[0];
      String outputDir = args[1];

      // Define input path and output path.
      Path mapInputPath = new Path(inputDir);
      Path mapOutputPath = new Path(outputDir + "-inter");
      Path reduceOutputPath = new Path(outputDir);

      // Define partition file path.
      Path partitionPath = new Path(outputDir + "-part.lst");

      // Configure map-only job for sampling.
      Job mapJob = new Job(getConf());
      mapJob.setJobName(mapJobName);
      mapJob.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
      mapJob.setMapperClass(WordMapper.class);
      mapJob.setNumReduceTasks(0);
      mapJob.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      mapJob.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
      TextInputFormat.setInputPaths(mapJob, mapInputPath);

      // Set the output format to a sequence file.
      mapJob.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
      SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(mapJob, mapOutputPath);

      // Submit the map-only job.
      int exitCode = mapJob.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
      if (exitCode != 0) { return exitCode; }

      // Set up the second job, the reduce-only.
      Job reduceJob = new Job(getConf());
      reduceJob.setJobName(reduceJobName);
      reduceJob.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

      // Set the input to the previous job's output.
      reduceJob.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
      SequenceFileInputFormat.setInputPaths(reduceJob, mapOutputPath);

      // Set the output path to the final output path.
      TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(reduceJob, reduceOutputPath);

      // Use identity mapper for key/value pairs in SequenceFile.
      reduceJob.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
      reduceJob.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      reduceJob.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
      reduceJob.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      reduceJob.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
      reduceJob.setNumReduceTasks(REDUCE_TASKS);

      // Use Total Order Partitioner.
      reduceJob.setPartitionerClass(TotalOrderPartitioner.class);

      // Generate partition file from map-only job's output.
      TotalOrderPartitioner.setPartitionFile(
          reduceJob.getConfiguration(), partitionPath);
      InputSampler.writePartitionFile(reduceJob, new InputSampler.RandomSampler(
          1, 10000));

      // Submit the reduce job.
      return reduceJob.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 2;
    }
  }

  public static class WordMapper extends
      Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String line = value.toString();
      for (String word : line.split("\\W+")) {
        if (word.length() == 0) { continue; }
        context.write(new Text(word), new IntWritable(1));
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I got this code from github.
I compared elapsed time of maps and reduces.
Regular wordcount does better job performing than total order paritioner.
Why is that?
Any optimizations or changes needed to meet average performance?
    Hashpartitioner performance vs TotalOrderPartitioner Performance?

Comment: Why do you want to compare the running time of wordcount to that of using a specific partitioner? I don't see the comparison that you make...

Comment: As total partitioner outputs map keys among all reducers. I want to check reduce time of both partitioner. Is it increase in total order partitioner?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HashPartitioner will perform better than TotalOrderPartitioner because the HashPartitioner does not have the overhead or running the InputSampler and writing the Partition file etc.,

TotalOrderPartitioner is only used when you need a globally sorted output and will be slower than HashPartitioner.